# how do I get the non-flag and non-option tokens after boost::program_options parses my command line args

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

In python, I can construct my [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) instance such that it will automatically filter out the options and non-option/flags into two different buckets:

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

With boost::program_options, how do I retrieve a list of tokens which are the remaining non-option and non-flag tokens?

e.g. If my program has flags

```
--foo 
--bar BAR
```

and I then pass in the command line:

```
--foo hey --bar BAR you
```

how can I get a list comprised solely of tokens "hey" and "you"

Comment: retagged for consistency with other boost libraries, that and boost-program-options already existed.

Comment: Ewwwww, the boost libraries are so inferior to Python's :'(. I had trouble with this too.

Comment: I hereby declare boost program options to the worst documented library ever (that says a lot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, you have to use a combination of [`positional_options_description`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#id2892937) and [*hidden options*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2893967). The idea is to (1) add a normal option and give it a name, maybe something like `--positional=ARG`, (2) don't include that option in the help description, (3) configure  `command_line_parser` to treat all positional arguments as if `--positional` was specified, and (4) retrieve the positional arguments using `vm["positional"].as< std::vector<std::string> >()`.

There is probably an example somewhere in the source tree but I don't have it on this machine right now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;    
po::positional_options_description m_positional;
po::options_description m_cmdLine;
po::variables_map m_variables;

m_cmdLine.add_options()
    (/*stuff*/)
    ("input", po::value<vector<string> >()->composing(), "")
;
m_positional.add("input", -1);
po::parsed_options parsed = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
                        .options(m_cmdLine)
                        .positional(m_positional)
                        .allow_unregistered()
                        .run();
// store, notify, etc
```

Then just get "input" named options as vector of strings and you are all set.